# How to enable filters in Backpack for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I am looking at the doc page: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-filters.

The simple question is: where must I call `$this->crud->filters()`? I tried to add at the end of `setupListOperation()` in my controller, but I don't see filters over my table. For curiosity: I assigned esit of a call to a var and dumped it, and it's an empty collection.

```php
protected function setupListOperation()
{
    CRUD::setFromDb(); // columns
    CRUD::column('assignmentTypes')->type('relationship');

    /**
     * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
     * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
     * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']);
     */

    dd($this->crud->filters()); // <<<<------------- EMPTY COLLECTION!
}
```

Please note that *manually adding* a filter works!

```php
$this->crud->addFilter([
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => 'first_name',
    'label' => 'First Nane'
], false,
    function ($value) { // if the filter is active
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'first_name', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
    }
);
```

But I ask you why `filters()` doesn't do something automatically.

Comment: Now I tried Backpack as newbie follows the docs and I think your upper code is only add a column to the table in view. The second code can uses to create filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$this->crud->filters()` or `CRUD::filters()` anywhere you'd like, but it makes most sense to use it in your `setupListOperation()` like you have, but AFTER you've already added some filters. Before the `addFilter()` statements the result is an empty collection, because there are no filters.

Backpack Filters are enabled automatically if you add one to your List operation.

Comment: I misunderstood the goal of `filters()`. I supposed that calling it will auto-enable standard filters based on listed fields. Thanks